# BAIDU map return error like as attached screen

Tags: baidu-map

[image][image: Baidu map integrate in ionic]
Map integrate with ionic app, it return error like as attached image.

Comment: You question needs clarificarion(code ,plugin used, error in english ...) ,plus try to make your description in english better so it could be understood well.

Comment: Thanks, but Baidu map it return error on chines language, it return from  *angular2-baidu-map* https://github.com/leftstick/angular2-baidu-map

Comment: Since its running but then giving an error, and this error contains api and a link containg apoconsole/key , maybe its just configration changed in their api and need some edits in api key . Checkctheir docs.